# Can a phase converter convert from DC

Tags: ac, dc, inverter, three-phase

Can a phase converter (1 to 3) convert directly from DC to three phase or does it have to invert it to AC first then convert to three phase?

Comment: It does so directly. Most AC/AC converters have an internal DC stage anyway.

Comment: But you need to make sure that the power supply to the controller can handle DC.  Almost all small (single-phase) converters have a DC internal link.